# Extract rowname of rows containing unique combination of TRUE FALSE

Tags: r

I am attempting to extract the rowname that marking rows that contain a single TRUE value.  Please see the following example.

```
                  Col1  Col2  Col3
Npat             FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Ttc30a1           TRUE FALSE FALSE
Gga1              TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
Gga3             FALSE FALSE FALSE
Gga2             FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I would like to extract the rownames of the rows containing a single unique "TRUE" value and retain information about which column the true value was in.
The desired output might look like:

```
                   Col1  Col2  Col3
Npat             FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Ttc30a1           TRUE FALSE FALSE
Gga2             FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I attempted to use grep and -grep but couldn't get it recognize multiple values in multiple columns.  I am sure there is a simple way to do this that I haven't been able to track down yet.

Comment: your question was easy, but consider to provide a reproducible example if possible:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Title of the post is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply treat booleans as if they were numeric.
In base R:

```
df[with(df, Col1 + Col2 + Col3  == 1) ,]
```

Comment: Imagine 100 columns.

Comment: In that case go with one of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `rowSums(df)==1`:

```
df1 <-read.table(text="Row  Col1  Col2  Col3
Npat             FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Ttc30a1           TRUE FALSE FALSE
Gga1              TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
Gga3             FALSE FALSE FALSE
Gga2             FALSE FALSE  TRUE",header=TRUE, row.names=1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df1[rowSums(df1)==1,]

         Col1  Col2  Col3
Npat    FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Ttc30a1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
Gga2    FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

somewhat similar approach: (more general solution)

use `apply` to sum row-wise.

```
df[apply(df,1,sum)==1,]
```